# Picking at random from a list, allowing no repetition

Tags: list-comprehension

```
import random
set = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
selection1 = random.sample(set, 2)
selection2 = random.sample(set, 3)
print(selection1,selection2)
```

How can I make it return a random selection without allowing repetition? Right now it's picking at random from the given list, but elements can repeat.

Comment: The obvious answer is to remove from the list the item you just picked. Or shuffle the list and then go through the elements in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By picking a random index of the list and removing the list element at that index.

If you're using the list elsewhere, you may want to create a copy of the list elsewhere in memory so you have the original.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
set = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
random.shuffle(set)
selection1 = set[0:2]
selection2 = set[2:5]
print(selection1,selection2)
```